# Best Collection to store a list of cards in Java?

Tags: java, collections

I have a Card class and now I want to create a Deck class. I'm looking at what's available in Collections to store the list of cards, knowing that I will need as much freedom in manipulating the cards as possible.

I want be able to insert new cards anywhere in the deck, shuffle them (Collections.shuffle() should work), peek at any card and take (remove) cards from the top, bottom and anywhere in the middle. Anything you can do with a pile of cards should be possible. No "only LIFO" restriction for example.

Here is what I have found so far and my issues with each:

- List: seems to provide as much freedom as I need but, clearly, I would need to add some helper functions for the simpler things such as picking the card on top. Still my favored solution for now.
- Stack: potentially does all I'm asking, but, from what I've read, is not the best implementation (extends Vector and is not *just* a stack in its behavior?)
- Deque: has functions I would like but does not seem to allow insertion of new items at any index (nor "getAt(index)" afaik)

Is there a premade class that's better than any of the above for what I'm trying to do? If nothing "perfect" exists, which class should I use as a base for expansion instead?

Of note: I do not know if I care about synchronization for now. I'm also looking at this from a Java 6 perspective, but I'm open to Java 7 solutions, especially if there's a ready-made solution for it.

Comment: you can get the last object in a list by l.get(l.size()-1).

Comment: @user2511414 this is not the preferred solution in a `List` if is implemented by `LinkedList`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza List is just a interface, what about ArrayList?

Comment: ArrayList all the way.

Comment: ArrayList or LinkedList if you are gonna to remove or add a lot

Comment: Just to throw out an idea besides an list, have you considered a Set? Unless you plan on having duplicate cards in your deck, a LinkedHashSet may meet your requirements

Comment: @monkybonk05 There is a need for duplicate entries (I plan to be able to deal as much with a classic deck of poker cards as with something like Magic the Gathering). As such, Set seems right out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) over an Arraylist.

A linked List provides you all the functionality that you were looking at of a Deque and also allows insertion and retrieval and indexed points. Still allows shuffle and also has peek methods where array list doesn't. It also has push and pop methods like a stack

Comment: Indeed! It implements List _and_ Deque which is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 9):

I'd go with a `List`-based approach. Your requirements are rather vague, but a `List` provides a good foundation for what you want to do. I'd suggest wrapping a `List` in your `Deck` class (rather than having `Deck` extend a concrete `List` class such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`). All `Deck` behavior should be defined by the `Deck` class; you certainly don't want to be automatically inheriting all `List` behavior, as it may not all be appropriate for your `Deck` object.

Comment: +1 for "All Deck behavior should be defined by the Deck class; you certainly don't want to be automatically inheriting all List behavior, as it may not all be appropriate for your Deck object."

Comment: Are there any specific points you feel I could clarify to help with the answer?

Comment: @leokhorn - Well, the requirement to have "as much freedom...as possible" is what I was thinking of when I wrote "vague". The specific operations you listed are well-supported by the `List` implementations (with various performance trade-offs). If that's the extent of the freedom you need, then no further clarification is needed. However, if you also need to partition according to suit, or according to card color, or by Pinochle rank, etc., then that would be helpful to know.

Comment: The operations listed are examples of the freedom I need, yes. While List has all of these, Deque would not for example. What do you mean by "partition" in this case? Ordering? or having sub-lists per card type? While I do need ordering and search capacity, I doubt I'll need anything further.

Comment: @leokhorn - By "partitioning" I meant organizing cards into categories, whether by ordering or by partitioning. Providing maximal freedom to organize according to an open-ended set of criteria is a difficult data structures problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with an ArrayList, you can still use collections.shuffle(), and it offers a constant time overhead when getting and adding elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a plain old array?
You can simply push cards forward and insert on the open slot, select anything from any slot at any time, shuffle it, and probably any other things you may need to do with it.
This works better wrapped in a class.

Upside:
- faster and lighter than any list / map / set class in the Java API.

Downside:
- you need to write the (very basic) methods to manipulate the array.

Comment: Why not use `ArrayList`, which essentially wraps an array, and has "methods to manipulate the array"?

Comment: I didn't think of the ArrayList.
I guess my answer isn't helpful at all unless you have a serious obsession over performance.

Comment: Wouldn't this become an issue for a dynamically sized deck? I won't have fixed-sized decks.

Comment: I didn't know that when I wrote it. Also the point of stackoverflow is having people pointing you to solutions, so that you can choose the one you think fits your problem better.

Comment: Assuming static sized, how would an array be faster than ArrayList, given that ArrayList is backed by an array, and all the JVM optimizations (such as inlining)?

Comment: Like I said, I didn't consider the ArrayList when I wrote that answer.
I already knew it was backed up by an array, but I don't have any deep understanding of the JVM's inner workings (very shallow, actually). My answer was probably also influenced by the fact I'm more used to native languages (like C / C++) where arrays are faster, because there's no VM in the back optimizing stuff for you. I already stated that this answer isn't good, you should be focusing in helping fix the issue rather than attempting to show your superiority by discussing me down.

Comment: I still appreciate the answer as it at least helped confirm the inadequacy of a given option.